# Identify Varistor TVR 20471

Tags: varistor, mov

I got this broken Varistor from an Eaton3S 550VA 300W UPS.
Marked TVR 20471*
I have tried my best to find a replacement but I can't find a similar one. Any tip or recommendation for a similar one that will work for a UPS would be very appreciated.

[image: Varistor TVR 20471*]

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I have put Thinking NTC resistors into production and I find they do crack and short after a while although used within specification.

Comment: This got totally fried and it had a non-resettable thermal link attached to it and it was also melted. I think this happened when I lost the neutral in the house when I reset  the 
RCD after a ground error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.thinking.com.tw/documents/en-TVR.pdf) is a link to a datasheet for the TVR  product line that shows your part on page 16.  It is from THINKING ELECTRONIC INDUSTRIAL Co. LTD in Taiwan.  The datasheet lists the part characteristics, so you should be able to find an equivalent, if you can't find the actual part.  They are available on [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&SearchText=tvr20471).

[image: tvr datasheet page]

Here are some potential subs found using the parametric search on Digikey:

[image: digikey subs]